# webkite Error HRESULT E_FAIL c#

Tags: c#, webkit, hresult

when i have 
used this code

```
<code>
webKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("Document.GetElementById('id').InvokeMember('click')");
</code>
```

i get this message error

> "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM
>   component."

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about C#, but it looks like the call is wrong. You are trying to evaluate javascript so call should look like

```
document.getElementById('id').click();
```

Please note that case also matters - at least in the webkitgtk version. Document and document do point to two different entities.